# mathspec selects the wrong math font

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, mathspec

I am trying to use [DejaVu Sans Light](https://dejavu-fonts.github.io/) as a math font.  It doesn't have a comprehensive set of math characters, but it has what I need (Roman numerals, beta, gamma, epsilon, and just a few other characters).

I've tried to select the font using

```
\setmathfont(Greek,Latin,Digits){DejaVu Sans ExtraLight}
```

in my preamble.  (The "Light" font must be called "ExtraLight" in the preamble; it won't load otherwise.)  This gives me a document with digits set in the Light font.  But no other characters are set in that font.  Instead, they are set in a heavier version of the same typeface: DejaVu Sans Oblique.  Here is a complete working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmathfont(Greek,Latin,Digits){DejaVu Sans ExtraLight}  
\begin{document} 
  Inline math: $\hat{\beta} = (X'X)^{-1}X'Y, 1234$.\\  
  Display math: $$\hat{\beta} = (X'X)^{-1}X'Y, 1234$$
\end{document}
```

And here is the result:

[image: the result]

This behavior puzzles me.  I can't see anything in the log file or the `mathspec` documentation that speaks to it.  And it's not as though the Light font has glyphs that the Oblique font lacks.  Is there a way to make sense of what `mathspec` is doing –– or at least to get it to render `$\beta$`, `$\gamma$`, and a few other characters in the Light font, while still using XeLaTeX?

Comment: @Sebastiano Please be careful when updating old links - don't randomly link to packages which are unrelated to the question! If you are not sure to which site the old link pointed to, you can use the https://www.waybackmachine.org/ to check. And as always when editing foreign posts: if your are not 1000% sure, don't do it!!! A broken link is better then a wrong link which changes the meaning of a question.

Comment: @samcarter I have seen that several site are empty, wrongs or inactive. I am 1000% sure. Can you prove it. However I remember your notices very well. Thanks a lot for waybackmachine.org.

Comment: @Sebastiano Sorry, try this link https://web.archive.org/

Comment: @samcarter I have finded a new link thank to you. Happy Eastern. Can you verificate the others old post that I have you modificate, please? Thanks again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no oblique version of DejaVu Sans ExtraLight on my system. So I get the normal weight too. But you could use the FakeSlant-Option:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmainfont[ItalicFont={DejaVu Sans ExtraLight},
             ItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.2}]{DejaVu Sans ExtraLight}
\setmathfont(Greek,Latin,Digits)[ItalicFont={DejaVu Sans ExtraLight},
                                 ItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.2}]{DejaVu Sans ExtraLight}
\begin{document}
X123 \itshape X124 \slshape X124


  Inline math: $\hat{\beta} = (X'X)^{-1}X'Y, 1234$.\\      Display math: \[\hat{\beta} = (X'X)^{-1}X'Y, 1234\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you -- that may prove helpful.  But for the present, I want to avoid both the Oblique typeface and the FakeSlant option altogether.  Instead, I want all math characters to be set in ExtraLight -- and I therefore want to stop mathspec from substituting Oblique for ExtraLight.  Do you know whether there is a way to do this?

Comment: But what should mathspec do instead? Print the variables upright?

Comment: Better to print them slanted in the lighter–weight typeface.  Which is exactly what your example does.  (I misunderstood it at first, but now I see that it solves my problem.)  Thank you.